# take_while borrows items, but I need ownership

Tags: rust, stream, iterator

I'd like to write my loop in a functional style starting with a `.take_while(|i| ... )` as it simplifies the logic, but because `take_while()` needs to run a predicate against an item before it removes it, it must borrow in the closure.

I need ownership of the item inside my predicate, so does this mean I can't use functional style here? Must I write a `while let Some(item) = my_iter.next() { ... }` and then deal with a bunch of `continue`s and `break`s?

Example:

```rust
struct Foo(u32);
impl Foo {
    fn predicate(self) -> bool { true }
}

fn main() {
    let items = vec!(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3));
    let mut iter = items.into_iter().take_while(|i: &Foo| i.predicate() );
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*i` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:8:59
  |
8 |     let mut iter = items.into_iter().take_while(|i: &Foo| i.predicate() );
  |                                                           ^^-----------
  |                                                           | |
  |                                                           | `*i` moved due to this method call
  |                                                           move occurs because `*i` has type `Foo`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Why do you need ownership to decide whether the condition is met? Maybe that's the problem to look at first.

Comment: `while let Some(item) = my_iter.next()` is essentially `for item in my_iter`.

Comment: If your predicate consumes the item, an explicit loop won't help you. Your item will be gone after checking the predicate either way.

Comment: In my actual use case it's the `StreamExt` iterator and I would like to move for lifetime reasons (the async block isn't happy with references in the future)

Comment: Yes the predicate consuming the item is absurd now you mention it, I just wanted a minimal reproducible example using `Iterator` but my actual code is in an async context with `Stream`s. It's a lifetime issue I thought for a moment ownership would solve, but of course inside `take_while` that's not appropriate. I will revisit and either edit or new question.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e438580917c0109bcceeaa4b6bf42844

Comment: I think you're trying to achieve something that you don't need. You asked here and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75545088/can-you-use-futuresstreamexttake-while-with-non-copy-items. What are you trying to do at all? Please show us more code an we can find a good solution for the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `Foo` clonable:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo(u32);
…
let items = vec![Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)];
let mut iter = items.into_iter().take_while(|i: &Foo| i.clone().predicate());
//                                                      ^^^^^^^
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=6fe8bcdc7ea843e48132f7154c4b88a7)