# Can you use futures::StreamExt::take_while with non-Copy items?

Tags: rust, stream, lifetime, rust-tokio

All of the examples I can find on SO and the [documentation](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.take_while) of `futures::stream::take_while` use Items which are `Copy` when using the adapter. But in my use case the Items I'm streaming over are non-`Copy`. This seems to render `take_while` impossible to use with async streams *any time the predicate needs to use [a reference to] the Item in the check*, which is basically always.

As far as I can see as it will always lead to a lifetime error since the return type of the future contains a lifetime.

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;

use futures_util::{Stream, StreamExt};
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::error::Error;
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::protocol::Message;


async fn process_messages(mut read: Pin<&mut impl Stream<Item = Result<Message, Error>>>) {
    read
     .take_while(|x: &Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>| 
         async { x; true } // would compile if removed the `x;`
     );
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let url = url::Url::parse("wss://127.0.0.1:12345").unwrap();

    let (ws_stream, _) = tokio_tungstenite::connect_async(url).await.expect("Failed to connect");

    let (_, read) = ws_stream.split();
    tokio::pin!(read);

    process_messages(read).await;
}
```

Error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:63
   |
13 |     read.take_while(|x: &Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>| async { x; true });
   |                         -                                   - ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                         |                                   |
   |                         |                                   return type of closure `[async block@src/main.rs:13:63: 13:80]` contains a lifetime `'2`
   |                         let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`

error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `x`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:13:63
   |
13 |     read.take_while(|x: &Result<Message, tungstenite::Error>| async { x; true });
   |                                                               ^^^^^^^^-^^^^^^^^
   |                                                               |       |
   |                                                               |       `x` is borrowed here
   |                                                               may outlive borrowed value `x`
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This limitation generalizes to other `StreamExt` methods where they take a `F where F: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> Fut,` such as `filter` and `skip_while`.

Comment: you can use `&x` to extract any information you need for your `async { }` block or you just return `future::ready(x.is_ok())`. It's not like `F where F: FnMut(&'a Self::Item) -> Fut +'a`.

Comment: Ah I follow you, it didn't occur to me the `FnMut` passed to `take_while` that returns a `Fut` could itself perform the information extraction. Thanks